# NGINX Configuration Issue: One Domain Works, Another Doesn't

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm facing an issue with my NGINX configuration where one of my domains works correctly, but the other doesn't. I have two domains (domain1.site and domain2.site) with their respective configurations in NGINX.

Here's the NGINX configuration for `domain1.site`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.site www.domain1.site;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1.site www.domain1.site;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.site/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.site/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8222;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And here's the NGINX configuration for `domain2.site`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.site www.domain2.site;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain2.site www.domain2.site;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.site/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.site/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3222;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

The issue is that while `domain1.site` works perfectly, `domain2.site` doesn't seem to respond (gives Welcome to Nginx! instead of page).

The websites are powered by Python Flask. I launch them through Gunicorn. Both Flask and Gunicorn are configured with the same ports as specified in the NGINX configurations.

I've tried disabling SSL for `domain2.site` to see if that makes a difference, but the issue persists. I've verified that DNS records are correctly pointing to the server's IP address.

Could you please help me troubleshoot this issue? Are there any specific steps I can take to identify the problem and resolve it? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: The different ports (8222, 3222) are intended?

Comment: @KlausD. Indeed, the different ports (8222, 3222) are intentional. Port 8222 is being used for one web application, while port 3222 is designated for another. This was a solution proposed to isolate and provide separate services on the same server.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that non-working domain's `server` blocks appear and that the `server_name` directive contains the correct values.

Comment: @RichardSmith , I've executed it. It displayed all the files, and the `server_name` directives are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by unlinking the default configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.